# Transfer my Joomla website to another folder, but not worked

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am facing a Problem in my Joomla Website, when I shifted all my Joomla website files and folder to a `Test` folder , I got the following error

`:- Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in includes/joomla.php.`

I resolved it by removing &(ampersand) from `includes/joomla.php`, but now I am facing problem that nothing is visible to me. All I can see is a blank page. Please take a look at topodds.com/Test

I have tried this code in includes/joomla.php but not succeed

```
$temp = func_get_args();
         array_shift( $temp );
         $args = array();
         foreach ($temp as $k => $v) {
            $args[] = &$temp[$k];
         }
```

Comment: Open configuration.php(placed at root directory of your website) and set these two variables as defined here, $error_reporting = 'maximum';     $debug = '1';  Now open your site's front-end in web browser. This will make all errors and warnings visible to you, By tracing those you can solve this issue

Comment: did you changed the tmp and cache paths on configuration.php?